# Visual Studio 2008 Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A2E0F92)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Visual Studio 2008 will suddenly quit when I'm manipulating the WebBrowser control in my WPF application.

This is in the Event Log:

> .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3053 -
>   Unrecoverable system error.
>
> .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3053 -
>   Fatal Execution Engine Error
>   (7A2E0F92) (0)

Does anyone know a cause or workaround for this error?

It happens when I change this XAML:

```
<WebBrowser
    Name="WebBrowserPreview"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Margin="5"
    Source="http://www.google.com"/>
```

to this:

```
<WebBrowser
    Name="WebBrowserPreview"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Margin="5" />
```

Comment: So it's only when you try and remove the Source attribute that it happens, it doesn't happen any other time?

Comment: Nothing else I've done has ever caused it.

Comment: Odd...I can't even repeat the problem...

Comment: I am seeing a similar issue related to WPF/XAML that I've been unable to resolve. Details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024946/visual-studio-hangs-in-wpf-design-view-net-runtime-version-2-0-50727-3053-fa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just CUT the whole section out.  Then PASTEed in a new <WebBrowser> tag from Notepad.

It didn't crash that time.

Weird.